# RIA: сессии Node.js и Ruby on Rails

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, socket.io

Пробую себя в разработке  [RIA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_Application)  проекта: на клиенте backbone.js, на серверной части node.js и ruby on rails. Рельсы отдают статику, тело страницы, так же реализуют api для отдачи данных. Для реализации реал-тайм части(подгрузки данных) используется node.js + socket.io. Для авторизации пользователей используется гем devise(ruby on rails).

Вопрос в том как обеспечить защиту от выдавания себя за другого пользователя на node.js.
Как реализовать механизм шаринга сессий между node.js и ruby on rails?

Облазил весь интернет, пересмотрел кучу своих вариантов решений, но конкретики и примеров не нашел.

Для того что бы хоть как то разобраться в теме изучал соединения с Node.js в [hall.com](http://hall.com) и [nitrous.io](http://nitrous.io) из чего сделал два предположения по реализации соответственно:

1. На node.js отправляется кука установленная рельсами, она может быть использована для проверки авторизации(существования такой сессии) обычным обращением в случае если сессии хранятся в базе данных, либо если в памяти рельс, то через обращение к апи реализованному на рельсах в специальном методе( [hall.com/s.json](https://hall.com/s.json) ) с отправкой принятой куки пользователя.
2. В nitrous.io со стороны клиента делается запрос по адресу  [nitrous.io/rainbow/auth_token](https://www.nitrous.io/rainbow/auth_token)(сторону рельс) где по видимому происходит получение auth_token'а предусмотренного для авторизации через хэш без паролей и логинов и далее этот токен используется для подключение к ноде, которая по всей видимости осуществляет проверку на существование этого токена в таблицах(коллекциях) пользователей.

Хотелось бы выяснить и увидеть на примере как реализовать правильно и более грамотно, но так же появляется вопрос что делать с временем жизни сессий или же не стоит об этом переживать и делать проверку только при подключении к Node.js пользователя через socket.io?

Буду очень рад услышать как ваши предположения, так и опыт в реализации приправленный ссылками и исходными кодами. К сожалению мои поиски что в англоязычном сегменте, а уж тем более в русскоязычном не увенчались успехом.